# Python: regex whole pattern substitution

Tags: python, regex

I'm practicing on python regex substitution with macros in property sheet.
In a brute-force way, I'm doing something like:

```
config_regex = re.compile(r'$(Configuration)')
test_str = r'<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\PropertySheets\Optimization.$(Configuration).props" />'
print config_regex.sub(r'Release', test_str)
```

However, the macro in my test string doesn't seem to be substituted. It still prints:

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\PropertySheets\Optimization.$(Configuration).props" />
```

Please help me out a little. Thanks.

Comment: Why use a regex here? Anyway, `$`, `(` and `)` must be escaped since they are special regex metacharacters.

Comment: You should use double quotes to escape regex meta-characters like so: `config_regex = re.compile(r"\$\(Configuration\)")`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: (Tim's comment is right)
If the regex starts with $ it will try to match at the <s>beginning</s> end of the string

Also, the parentheses have a special meaning in the exp (capture)

You should try with \ before those characters, or use the escape function in the re module

Comment: `$` matches at the end of the string.